# Cant go deeper than root, LINQ to (Funds)XML, C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I'm working with a specific FundsXML-Schema trying to get all `Assets`s of a specific XML-File to iterate through.

Short example of xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FundsXML xmlns="http://www.fundsxml.org/XMLSchema/3.0.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="3.0.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fundsxml.org/XMLSchema/3.0.5 FundsXML3.0.5.xsd">
<Date>2015-02-27</Date>
...
<AssetMasterData>
   <Asset>
      <SecurityCodes>
         <ISIN>XXXXXXXXXXXX</ISIN>
      </SecurityCodes>
   </Asset>
   ...
   <Asset>
</AssetMasterData>
</FundsXML>
```

I want to iterate through `Asset`s in there. I tried:

```
XDocument xmlTree = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
XElement root = xmlTree.Root;
foreach (XElement f in root.Descendants())
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(f.Name.ToString() +" ; "+f.Value.ToString());
        }
```

Output: {http://www.fundsxml.org/XMLSchema/3.0.5}Date ; 2015-02-27

The second part would be to read ISIN of each `Asset` node.
But I hadn't time to do this, because I'm failing at the first part.

EDIT:

Solution was to search for namespace+name:

```
foreach (XElement f in root.Descendants("{http://www.fundsxml.org/XMLSchema/3.0.5}Asset"))
```

Best solution in my opinion:

```
foreach (XElement f in root.Descendants(xmlTree.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()+"Asset"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your XML is in a namespace, you need to add the namespace information to the Descendants query.

You can see an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can try to get the

```
roots.Descendants()
```

Without filtering and check the nodes that it returns to confirm this.

Comment: But isn't the user looking for the element value, not the element name?? EDIT: so if you look for descendants() without specifying the element name it will dig down to the first element that has a value??

Comment: Yeah, but to get the value he must first address the elements by their right name. He is not finding any "Asset" to iterate over because, I think, he is not looking them by their complete namespace+element name. EDIT: Descendants() will return ALL elements under root.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data you've provided

```
<Asset></Asset>
```

doesn't appear to have any data in it. You would need to get

```
foreach (XElement f in root.Descendants("ISIN"))
```

I think anyway. If there's no actual text then you will get a blank or empty value?? So it sounds like it's returning what you're asking for??

Comment: Yeah the sample is very short, because the original File has over 2000 rows. I just wanted to show the structure of the XML.
root.Descendants("ISIN") is null (like all other tries of mine) and not an empty string or something like that

Comment: You said it's returning empty, not null. Have you tried going to ISIN?